# Can I write the address of a variable to any data type in C?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct

I want to build a simplified version of the Linux Command `find`.
I am using an array of structs to save data about the options I'm getting from the command line:

```
struct my_option
{
    short id;              //
    const char *option;    // check valid/invalid option
    short needs_arg;       // check this options requires an argument
    short opt_count;       // count number of paths
    int   first_arg;       // first argument
    int   last_arg;        // last argument
};

static struct my_option opt[] =
{
    {OPT_TYPE     , "-type",    REQUIRES_1_ARGUMENT,        0, 0, 0},
    {OPT_USER     , "-user",    REQUIRES_1_ARGUMENT,        0, 0, 0},
    {OPT_NOUSER   , "-nouser",  REQUIRES_NO_ARGUMENT,       0, 0, 0},
    {OPT_GROUP    , "-group",   REQUIRES_1_ARGUMENT,        0, 0, 0},
    {OPT_NOGROUP  , "-nogroup", REQUIRES_NO_ARGUMENT,       0, 0, 0},
    {OPT_NAME     , "-name",    REQUIRES_1_ARGUMENT,        0, 0, 0},
    {OPT_PATH     , "-path",    REQUIRES_1_ARGUMENT,        0, 0, 0},
    {OPT_PRINT    , "-print",   REQUIRES_NO_ARGUMENT,       0, 0, 0},
    {OPT_LS       , "-ls",      REQUIRES_NO_ARGUMENT,       0, 0, 0},
    {OPT_PATHLIST , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
/* OPT_PATHLIST has to be the last entry in the struct */
};
```

In the last Index of the `opt[]` you can see the entry `OPT_PATHLIST` and all other fields set to `0`.

If multiple paths are passed to my find command, I want to save them into this struct, but how would I do this?
Would I just use global String variables which hold the actual path-Strings and save their addresses into the fields `_option, _needs_arg, _opt_count, ...`? I should rather ask, can I even do this? Saving addresses to variables of any type?

An example would be:
`newfind /dev /etc -ls`
Which should print some information about files in the two directories `/dev`and `/etc`
How would you save the strings or addresses of variables which hold `/dev` and `/etc`into the `struct my_option` with ID `OPT_PATHLIST`

Another option I considered would be:
loop over the paths from the command line input
and just add them onto the `char *option` such that the String `option` would be `"/dev /etc"` in the end, instead of using multiple variables for the paths. Maybe thats better and easier.

Thank you for your help! I'm doing this for an assignment for university.
EDIT: as someone suggested just to use getopt(3), I'm not allowed to do that. I'm implementing my_getopt()

Comment: It seems you're reinventing the wheel. See [`getopt` and `getopt_long`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html). There are also plenty of existing libraries which offer even more advanced parsing of command-line options.

Comment: use https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt and use linked list or array of pointers for the options which may have more than one instance

Comment: Why do you have to save them?  argv isn't going anywhere.  You just need the index and the count.

Comment: I should have added: I am not allowed to use lib function getopt :(
argv isn't going anywhere is true and I might just use it like this, but this is my assignment and I hate the instructions because i HAVE to do it like this for some reason

Comment: What are you instructions? I'm not clear on what your constraints are, which parts you can change and which you can't.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I have to implement my_getopt() which should test paths, options and arguments passed and return codes if parsing was successful or encountered errors...
By parsing I mean filling up the ```opt[]``` from my post with the data passed from command line to later on work on it in the functions ```do_dir()``` and ```do_file()```

Comment: Why are you trying to store paths in `opt` or in any `struct my_option`? If you need to store paths, make an array of `char *` and store pointers to (the first elements of) strings in the elements of that array. It is not clear what you are trying to do or why.

Comment: look at the getopt source https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/getopt.c it is well commented and write your own (maybe simplified version)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use an array for the paths, and a linked list for the rules and actions, and use [nftw()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) for the directory tree traversal.

You could just reuse the argv[] array for the paths (like getopt() and getopt_long() do), but a separate array is in many ways simpler:

```c
static size_t   max_paths = 0;
static size_t   num_paths = 0;
static const char **path  = NULL;

void path_add(const char *p)
{
    if (num_paths >= max_paths) {
        size_t  temp_max = num_paths + 16;
        void   *temp;
        temp = realloc(path, temp_max * sizeof path[0]);
        if (!temp) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        max_paths = temp_max;
        path = temp;
    }

    path[num_paths++] = p;
}
```

Above, `num_paths` is the number of paths in the `path[]` array (which is a an array of pointers to each path), and `max_paths` is the number of array entries currently allocated for.

As to the options/rules/predicates, I would use a singly-linked list,

```c
enum {
    OPT_UNKNOWN = 0,  /* Optional, I just like to reserve zero */
    OPT_TYPE,
    OPT_NAME,
    /* All option types here */
};

struct option {
    struct option *next;
    int            type;
    const char    *arg;
};
```

Your option parsing loop would examine the the current command-line argument, and if recognized, construct a `struct option` with .type matching the type of that option, and .arg pointing to its argument if that option takes one, NULL otherwise.  For simplicity, I would build the list in reverse order, then reverse it when all parameters have been processed:

```c
static struct option  *options = NULL;

static void options_add(int type, const char *arg)
{
    struct option *opt;

    opt = malloc(sizeof *opt);
    if (!opt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    opt->next = options;
    opt->type = type;
    opt->arg  = arg;

    options = opt;
}

static void options_finish(void)
{
    struct option *list = NULL;
    while (options) {
        struct option *curr = options;
        options = options->next;
        curr->next = list;
        list = curr;
    }
    options = list;
}
```

Whenever `nftw()` calls your callback function, that function must walk through the options list, to determine what is done with the current directory entry.

Answer (score -3):

To answer the question, I think you can write the address of a variable to any data type in C implicitily with our old ampersand friend &variable.

Comment: First, you cannot store addresses in all types because some types do not have enough bits. For example, an eight bit `char` generally does not have enough bits to store the addresses used in almost all systems. Second, you cannot store addresses in all types because some types do not have suitable conversions defined. Third, you cannot even store all addresses in all pointer types, as C has some limitations on what it defines for pointer conversions.